# Set height for position absolute in div with overflow auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with sticky footer which has absolute position,

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer  
    </div>
  </div>

body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  overflow: auto; 

  background: blue;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;

  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;

  background: red;

}
```

When I do scroll down my footer also scrolled, when I remove height:100% footer works fine but I need height:100% for my scroll bar for wrapper because I disabled it in body (I need do it). I want to retain height:100% for body and .wrapper but that footer was always at bottom. How can I do it using css ?

Comment: You need to use the position:fixed for the .footer class.

Comment: I need in order to when page is not full - footer was at the bottom, when page has many content footer should be after content in the end.

Comment: Like position:relative, only when page is not full footer should be at the end...

Answer (score 0):

If you need your footer to always be at the bottom look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2n9okg1b/3/

In the fiddle I amd using `poition: fixed;` in the footer CSS. Fixing the position tells the browser to always keep the elements where you defined them to be.

**Update**

I have updated the fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/2n9okg1b/3/ 
With this update I detect with jQuery if the footer is below the window. If the footer is below the window I set the footer position to fixed. If the footer is not below the window I set the footer's position to relative. This allows the footer to always be at the bottom of the content or at the bottom of the window.

Comment: How can I do so that the footer was after the content? 
 
Like position:relative, only when page is not full footer should be at the end..

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/2n9okg1b/2/ I use jQuery to detect if the footer is below the content, if so I set the position to fixed. If the footer is not below the window I set the position to relative.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to listen for the window re-sizing event, so that you can re-position your footer.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue, use `height: 100vh;` i hope works for you!

Comment: This is an answer to the question.